# Committing changes to branch I got by downloading zip from GitHub

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I'm working on a `repository` that has two `branches`: `Master`, and `Release1`.

The branch I need is `Release1`. I went to the site and tried to clone it, but no matter what I did I got the `Master` branch cloned.

So I gave up and downloaded the branche's zip to my file system. I added it to `Eclipse` and worked on it.

Now I need to commit my changes. But neither the branch nor the repository show up in my visual tool.

When I try to add a `local repository` the visual tool tells me the folder is not a repository.

Is there a solution? I have quite a few changes on my local project and I have to commit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Zip download is not a Git repository, it's only a collection of the files at that moment in time. Here's a way you might be able to get your changes into the repository:

- Clone the repository properly
- Copy your current files into the cloned directory
- `git status` and `git diff` to check that the changes are what you expect
- `git commit`

When you cloned the repository the first time, you *were* getting both branches - a Git clone is a fully copy of everything: every branch, all history, etc. The default branch is typically `master`. After you clone, if you want to switch to the other branch, use `git checkout Release1`.

Comment: Kristján is there a command like git checkout Release1 through the github visual tool, or Eclipse? I'm kind of used to the visual tool and prefer not to go command line.

Comment: Yep, in Egit, branches are in Team > Switch To. GitHub Desktop has branch selection in the top left.

Comment: In GitHub for mac you can do Repository > Show Branches, and go to the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

What GUI are you using? When trying to clone you have to make sure you change the branch you are cloning from (usually in a drop down menu or you may have to type it in). If you can successfully clone from Master, than you should be able to change to or "checkout" Release1  branch.

Just downloading the zip, just gets you the source code and doesn't have any connection to git. To save and push your changes you will need to clone the repository and checkout Release1

Comment: Generally you wouldn't change the branch you clone from. Clone once, then switch branches.